# Swift2.0で、Reachability.swiftのエラーハンドリングの書き方がわからない。

Tags: swift

お世話になります。

Swift2.0で、

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/scientre/20150527/get_network_status_in_swift

の記事に従って、
`Reachability` というライブラリを用いてインターネット接続の検出をしたいと思っています。

記事最下部の説明の通り、
「ネットワークに接続や切断したときに何か処理をしたいという場合の書き方」として、

```
let reachability = AMReachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
// エラー（Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled）
        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            print("インターネット接続あり")
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            print("インターネット接続なし")
        }

reachability.startNotifier()
// エラー（Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled）
```

とすると、

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

というエラーがでます。

どのようにエラーハンドリングを書けばいいのでしょうか？

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「reachabilityForInternetConnection」メソッドはコードを見ると「ReachabilityError」というenumをエラーとして投げるので、次の様に、do-try-catchで、「ReachabilityError」を捉えるような、エラー制御を書けば良いと思います。

```
do {
    let reachability = try AMReachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    if reachability.isReachable() {
        print("インターネット接続あり")
    } else {
        print("インターネット接続なし")
    }
} catch let error as ReachabilityError {
    // エラー処理
} catch let error as NSError {
    // NSErrorが投げられた場合
} catch {
    // その他ハンドル出来なかったもの
}
```

「reachabilityForInternetConnection」メソッドのように「throws」が宣言された、エラーを投げるメソッドは「try」付きで呼び出す必要があります。「Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled」はそのことを意味しています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
このコードと通り書かせていただきますと、`let reachability = try AMReachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()`の行で、
「Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive」
というエラーが出ます。

Comment: 投げられる可能性があるエラーがハンドルし切れていないということですね。こちらの環境（Xcode 7.1.1) + 最新版のReachability (上記の記事からリンクされているGit) では起きなかったのですが、他のエラーが投げられる可能性があるということですね。少しコードを追加しました。ここまでは必要ないかしれませんが、念入りのコードにしました。

Comment: 丁寧に説明いただきましてありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。